# Check if dynamic variable is empty - Batch

Tags: batch-file, variables

I want to check, if a dynamic variable is empty. I have the variables f1-f9 and now I want to check like this:

```
IF f%ERRORLEVEL%=" " //do something
```

But this doesnt work. I also tried:

```
IF !f%ERRORLEVEL%!
```

But this doesn't work either.

EDIT:

The variables `f1-f9` are created like this:

```
set "f1= "
set "f2= "
...
```

`%ERRORLEVEL%` contains a number between 1-9 (comes from a choice command)

Comment: I don't know what "_dynamic_ variable" means to you, but in the `set /?` help screen the _"dynamic variables"_ are `%time%`, `%date%`, `%random%`, etc, that is, variables that change their values with no direct action from the user (hence they are _dynamic_, not _static_)...

Comment: `if defined f%ErrorLevel% echo f%ErrorLevel%` or `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` and then `if "!f%ErrorLevel%!"=="" ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to match the value of f1 which is  with `" "` So simply fix it by adding souble quotes around %f1% see example:

```
IF %ERRORLEVEL%==1 (
    IF "%f1%"==" " (
        set "f1=%turn%"
    ) ELSE (
        goto draw_screen
    )
```

But as per you question to simply your script, you firstly need `delayedexpansion` and then some straighforward if testing:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "f1= "
set "f2= "
set "f3= "
set "errorlevel=2"

if "!f%errorlevel%!"==" " (
    set "f%errorlevel%=%turn%"
) else (
    goto draw_screen
)
```

I use f1-3 only for simplifying the answer and obvisouly mimicing `errorlevel` as a test. It is a single if statement which will match any errorlevel, you can test it by changing errorlevel value above.